# How to give a class all the values of a created object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class

If within a class constructor and I lookup an object that contains many values, how can I make it so that class will obtain all those values?

For example, if this is my object:

```
const myObject = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}
```

This is my class:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    const object = createMyObject(); // This function returns the above myObject
  }
}
```

Now, how do I make it so `MyClass` has all the values of `myObject` so I can do something like:

```
const class = new MyClass();
console.log(class.a);
// 1
```

Comment: Why not just loop through and set the properties?

Comment: I could, but I was hoping there was some syntax sugar

Comment: Well you could do `Object.assign(this, object)` I guess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the object with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries) and assign the key/value pairs to the class.

```js
function createMyObject() {
  return {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3
  };
}

class MyClass {
  constructor() { 
    const object = createMyObject();
    const entries = Object.entries(object);
    for (const [key, value] of entries) {
      this[key] = value;
    }
  }
}

const o = new MyClass();

console.log(o.a);
console.log(o.b);
console.log(o.c);
```

Comment: Yeah, this does work, I was hoping for something simpler like `this = ...object` but I suppose I'm limited to a for loop.

Comment: You could do something like `this.props = { ...createMyObject() };` but then you would need to reference `props` in your log: `console.log(o.props.a)` for example. What you can't do is `this = { ...object }` because you'll get an invalid left-hand side assignment error. @GaryHoliday

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```js
function createMyObject(){
    return {
        a:1,
        b:2,
        c:3
    }
}
class MyClass{
    constructor(){
        Object.assign(this,createMyObject())
    }
}
const res = new MyClass();
console.log(res.a)
console.log(res.b)
console.log(res.c)
```